# Prove that $\overline{A \cap B}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a set $S$, then $\overline{A \cap B}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$.

I tried to prove that $A \cap B=A \cup B$ because I didn't realize that the overline meant to prove it for the *closure* of the sets.

So, now I am confused about how to prove for closure. I cannot find it in my textbook, and by some "similar" proofs online led me to conclude that $\overline{A \cap B}=\overline{A \cup B}$ but I somehow don't know if this is true, or how to prove it exactly. So, now I am not sure if I understand this principle at all.

Comment: this is wrong: take $A= \emptyset$ and $B= S$.

Comment: I think here that it means the *complement* (everything not in the set). So if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a set $X$, then $\overline{A} = \{x \in X : x \not \in A\}$.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture? Draw a Venn-diagram of A and B, and then see how both parts of the equality look in that venn-diagram.

Comment: What is $\overline{A}$? You're calling it the "closure"? The closure of a set doesn't mean anything unless you have a topology on the set. I'm fairly certain that $\overline{A}$ is supposed to be referring to the complement of $A$ in $S$.

Comment: If this is the complement then you should replace the tags first and have a look at [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 3):

Like I said in my comment, I'm pretty sure that $\overline A$ is referring to the complement of $A$ in $S$. The way to prove this problem is to just blindly "chase elements":

Let $x\in\overline{A\cap B}$. Then $x\in S$ but $x\notin A\cap B$. Therefore $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$. This precisely means $x\in\overline A\cup\overline B$, so $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline A\cup\overline B$.

I would encourage you do the other direction on your own. Just follow the same procedure I did above, and follow the definitions to show $\overline A\cup\overline B\subseteq\overline{A\cap B}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I didnt see your comment at first...I think you are right.  I have worked with closures a little bit before, so what you said makes sense to me too, that the bar must mean compliment here.  I never saw that notation other than for closures  So....now I think I can do this problem for sure.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: @PBJ no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let M = (A ∩ B)' and N = A' U B'

Let x be an arbitrary element of M then x ∈ M ⇒ x ∈ (A ∩ B)'

⇒ x ∉ (A ∩ B)

⇒ x ∉ A or x ∉ B

⇒ x ∈ A' or x ∈ B'

⇒ x ∈ A' U B'

⇒ x ∈ N

Therefore, M ⊂ N …………….. (i)

Again, let y be an arbitrary element of N then y ∈ N ⇒ y ∈ A' U B'

⇒ y ∈ A' or y ∈ B'

⇒ y ∉ A or y ∉ B

⇒ y ∉ (A ∩ B)

⇒ y ∈ (A ∩ B)'

⇒ y ∈ M

Therefore, N ⊂ M …………….. (ii)

Now combine (i) and (ii) we get

M = N

(A ∩ B)' = A' U B'

Comment: Are you using the apostrophe to denote the closure of the set?

Comment: Yes $\overline{A \cap B} = (A \cap B)'$

Comment: If you want me to change I can but its same thing

Comment: No, dont change it.  That's fine.  Thank you!

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)